# Create a range of strings from end values

Tags: ruby, range

I use irb.

I write the code below.
`"ax".."bc"`
I expect
`"ax""ay""az""ba"bb""bc"`

But the result is just
`"ax".."bc"`

How should I correct?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
> puts ("ax".."bc").to_a
ax
ay
az
ba
bb
bc
```

Answer (score 3):

The range `'ax' .. 'bc'` does represent the values that you expect but it doesn't generate them until it really needs to (as a way to save time and space in case you don't end up using each value).  You can access them all via an interator or conversion to an array:

```
r = 'ax' .. 'bc' # => "ax" .. "bc"
r.class # => Range
r.to_a # => ["ax", "ay", "az", "ba", "bb", "bc"]
r.to_a.class # => Array
r.each {|x| puts x}
ax
ay
az
ba
bb
bc
```

Answer (score 2):

Range is a builtin in construct, internally storing start and ending point (and whether it's an end-inclusive range) for efficiency. So IRB will just show you the literal for it.

What do you want to do?